# In C, why can't I set a value of a element in a 2D array?

Tags: c

When I assign a pixel to a var why can I not assign it a value?

```
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
        RGBTRIPLE pixel = image[i][j];
        double avgcolor = (pixel.rgbtBlue + pixel.rgbtGreen + pixel.rgbtRed) / 3.0;

        avgcolor = round(avgcolor);
        pixel.rgbtBlue = avgcolor; <-- fails
        pixel.rgbtRed = avgcolor; <-- fails
        pixel.rgbtGreen = avgcolor; <-- fails

        image[i][j].rgbtBlue = avgcolor; <-- works
        image[i][j].rgbRed = avgcolor; <-- works
        image[i][j].rgbtGreen = avgcolor; <-- works
    }
}
return;
```

Comment: fails how?  What is RGBTRIPLE ?

Comment: @jdog Why did you decide that you can not assign a value?

Comment: This function should change an image to grayscale. The pixel... lines do NOT work. If you comment out the image[i][j].rgb lines that set the new color values the image doesn't get changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following line makes a new copy of the object:

```
RGBTRIPLE pixel = image[i][j];
```

You need to maintain a reference to the original object, so you have to use a pointer type:

```
RGBTRIPLE *pixel = &image[i][j];
```

Now you can do:

```
pixel->rgbtBlue = avgcolor;
pixel->rgbtRed = avgcolor;
pixel->rgbtGreen = avgcolor;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `=` operator will **copy** your struct. I.e., after calling `RGBTRIPLE pixel = image[i][j];`, `pixel` is a copy of `image[i][j]`, so updating it does **not** update the original `image[i][j]`.

One way around this is to use a pointer:

```c
GBTRIPLE* pixel = &image[i][j];
double avgcolor = (pixel.rgbtBlue + pixel.rgbtGreen + pixel.rgbtRed) / 3.0;

avgcolor = round(avgcolor);
pixel->rgbtBlue = avgcolor;
pixel->rgbtRed = avgcolor;
pixel->rgbtGreen = avgcolor;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RGBTRIPLE pixel = image[i][j];
```

I think it does work.

But I think you are misunderstanding the relationship between
the left-hand side (lhs) and the right-hand side (rhs)  of the assignment operator.

In this case the assignment works but does nothing to change the values in
the array `image`.

`image[i][j]` being on the right is evaluated as a read-only value, copying over the contents of `pixel` each time the `j` loop iterates.

I believe you solved this on your own, so I will leave it at that.
However I think you could collapse this into a single loop, and a single assignment within it.